# Keeping a footnote on the same page in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How do you keep a footnote together on the same page if it is a bit longer, it spills over to the next side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it depends on where the footnote is referenced from.

If it's from the top of the page (say) then the space available for the content can be shrunk to allow for the longer footnote (I was going to try and illustrate this but it didn't look right). However, if the footnote is from the last paragraph then the choices are to overflow the footnote into the following page (which is what you are seeing) or move the paragraph onto the next page. This would leave a lot (depending on the length of the paragraph and the footnote) of white space on the page - which is not good from a typographical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

> ### Create a footnote or endnote continuation notice
>
> If a footnote or endnote is too long to fit on a page, you can create a continuation notice to >let readers know that a footnote or endnote is continued on the next page.
>
> 1. Make sure that you are in Draft view by clicking Draft next to View on the status bar.
> 2. On the References tab, in the Footnotes group, click Show Notes.
>
>    [image: Word Ribbon Image]
> 3. If your document contains both footnotes and endnotes, a message appears. Click View >footnote area or View endnote area, and then click OK.
> 4. In the note pane list, click Footnote Continuation Notice or Endnote Continuation Notice.
> 5. In the note pane, type the text that you want to use for the continuation notice. For >example, type Endnotes continued on the next page.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP012265221033.aspx)